# Not able to print the expression in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to print the expression using {{ }} on angularjs. But I am not able to print it.

```
<html>
  <head ng-app="myapp">
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type="text" ng-model="exp">
        {{ exp }}
     </input>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting {{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code. At first create a div element which defines your `ng-app` in the body section. In there you can use other tags, like input and div. Inputs don't have a closing tag. The output expression in between your inputs does not make sense at all, since you want to bind the input to a variable available in your page, and not to itself. Then you can use the double bracket notation to insert the `exp`. Also don't forget to import the angular library in your head and for best practice insert the doctype at the beginning of your file. Your example app could look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="">
      <p><input type="text" ng-model="exp"></p>
      <p>{{exp}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more information have a look at [w3schools angularjs introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp).

Comment: Thanks a lot..Since I am beginner to angularJS your explanation helps me a lot:)

Comment: You should also except and/or upvote answers that are helping/solving your issue. ;)

Comment: Done...Im new to Stack overflow:)